# Why do many init.d scripts end in "exit $?"?

Tags: linux, bash, init.d, centos6.5

I've seen a lot of strange quirks in CentOS 6.5's init.d scripts, but one pattern I've seen **at the end** of most of these scripts is

```
case "$1" in
    # ... commands here
esac
exit $?
```

What is the purpose of "`exit $?`" here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes the script return the return code of the last significant command to the calling init system. Whenever a command exits, its return code is stored on `$?` by the shell.

It's actually not really necessary to explicitly specify `$?` but scripters probably just include it to be clear about what it intends to do.

> **exit: exit [n]**
>
> Exit the shell.
>
> Exits the shell with a status of N.  If N is omitted, the exit status
>   is that of the last command executed.

I also hope you don't actually mean `eend $?` of `OpenRC`:

> **eend retval [string ]**
>
> If retval does not equal 0 then output the string using eerror and !! in square > brackets at the end of the line. Otherwise output ok in square brackets at the end of the line. The value of retval is returned.

See [source](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/8/runscript.htm).

Comment: So it is for code clarity? (A snippet saying "Don't overwrite the exit code because I am relying on it"?)

Comment: That could be one thing. And if it's in the end of the script, `exit` can also be just omitted as the shell would return by default whatever value `$?` has.